# Is it possible to increase the size of thumbnails in the filename conflict dialog?

Tags: nautilus, icons

When the files being moved or copied are images, bigger thumbnails would make it easier to see the file contents and decide on how to solve conflicts. Is there any way the default thumbnail size in the filename conflict dialog can be increased?